# Pyspark DataFrame - Escaping &amp;

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have some large (~150 GB) csv files using semicolon as the separator character. I have found that some of the fields contain a html encoded ampersand `&amp;` The semicolon is getting picked up as a column separator so I need to way to escape it or replace `&amp;` with `&` while loading the dataframe.

As an example, I have the following csv file:

```
ID;FirstName;LastName
1;Chandler;Bing
2;Ross &amp; Monica;Geller
```

I load it using the following notebook:

```
df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ";").option("header","true").csv('/mnt/input/AMP test.csv')
df.show()
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
+---+---------+--------+
| ID|FirstName|LastName|
+---+---------+--------+
|  1| Chandler|    Bing|
|  2|Ross &amp|  Monica|
+---+---------+--------+
```

Whereas what I'm looking for is:

```
+---+-------------+--------+
| ID|    FirstName|LastName|
+---+-------------+--------+
|  1|     Chandler|    Bing|
|  2|Ross & Monica|  Geller|
+---+-------------+--------+
```

I have tried using `.option("escape", "&amp;")` but that escaping only works on a single character.

**Update**

I have a hacky workaround using RDDs that works at least for small test files but I'm still looking for a proper solution escapes the string while loading the dataframe.

```
rdd = sc.textFile('/mnt/input/AMP test.csv')
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x.replace('&amp;', '&'))

rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/mnt/input/AMP test escaped.csv")

df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ";").option("header","true").csv('/mnt/input/AMP test escaped.csv')
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with dataframes directly. It helps if you have at least 1 file you know that does not contains any `&amp;` to retrieve the schema.

Let's assume such a file exists and its path is "valid.csv".

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# I acquire a valid file without the &amp; wrong data to get a nice schema
schm = spark.read.csv("valid.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True, sep=";").schema


df = spark.read.text("/mnt/input/AMP test.csv")

# I assume you have several files, so I remove all the headers.
# I do not need them as I already have my schema in schm.
header = df.first().value
df = df.where(F.col("value") != header)


# I replace "&amp;" with "&", and split the column
df = df.withColumn(
    "value", F.regexp_replace(F.col("value"), "&amp;", "&")
).withColumn(
    "value", F.split("value", ";")
)

# I explode the array in several columns and add types based on schm defined previously
df = df.select(
    *(
        F.col("value").getItem(i).cast(col.dataType).alias(col.name)
        for i, col in enumerate(schm)
    )
)
```

here is the result :

```
df.show()
+---+-------------+--------+
| ID|    FirstName|LastName|
+---+-------------+--------+
|  1|     Chandler|    Bing|
|  2|Ross & Monica|  Geller|
+---+-------------+--------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't a way to escape this complex char `&amp;` only using `spark.read.csv` and the solution is like you did your "workaround":

- `rdd.map`: This function already replaces in all columns the value `&amp;` by `&`
- It is not necessary to save your rdd in a temporary path, just passes it as `csv` parameter:

```py
rdd = sc.textFile("your_path").map(lambda x: x.replace("&amp;", "&"))

df = spark.read.csv(rdd, header=True, sep=";")
df.show()

+---+-------------+--------+
| ID|    FirstName|LastName|
+---+-------------+--------+
|  1|     Chandler|    Bing|
|  2|Ross & Monica|  Geller|
+---+-------------+--------+
```